# Temperature function issue in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I have written some code to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit (and vice versa) allowing the user to choose which way to convert before they input the value to be converted.

The program seems to be working fine when I choose option 1 (to go from F to C) - but when I choose option 2 (C to F) it reverts me to option 1.

I'm obviously doing something wrong (I suspect it may be something to do with my conditional True or False step).

Here's my code:

```
def instructions():
    print('This is a program to convert from F to C or C to F')

def chooser():
    choice = input('Choose:\n1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius\nor\n2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit\n--> ')
    if choice is 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def F_userInput():
    fahrenheit = input('Please enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: ')
    return float(fahrenheit)

def f2c(temperature):
    celsius = (temperature - 32) * 5/9
    return celsius

def C_userInput():
    celsius = input('Please enter the temperature in Celsius: ')
    return float(celsius)

def c2f(temperature):
    fht = (temperature * 9/5) + 32
    return fht

def output(result):
    print 'Your coverted temperature is', result

def main():
    instructions()
    chooser()
    if True:
        temperature = F_userInput()
        result = f2c(temperature)
    else:
        temperature = C_userInput()
        result = c2f(temperature)
    output(result)

main()
```

Please note - I have managed to write a simpler program to do this conversion - but I am noodling around with functions to help me understand them better (and how to call certain functions and not others).

PS please feel free to give me any tips/advice/alternative ways of doing this.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you think `if True:` will select your `else` branch?

Comment: You need to use this expression to compare int : `if choice == 1`, and also convert the input to integer..

Comment: @PRMoureu - that's true (`is` tests object identity, not value equality, and is the wrong tool for comparing ints) but not the whole problem.

Comment: `if chooser()` probably better reflects your intentions

Comment: Not a Python expert, but "if true" sounds suspicious.  Shouldn't it be something like " if Chooser() "..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your main function, your if statment just has

```
if True: 
    do_stuff()
```

with no reference to a variable. 
Try this for your main method, maybe it will help?

```
def main():
    instructions()
    some_var_name = chooser()
    if some_var_name == True:
        temperature = F_userInput()
        result = f2c(temperature)
    else:
        temperature = C_userInput()
        result = c2f(temperature)
    output(result)
```

I think when you write

```
if True:
    do_stuff()
```

This statement will always execute. There is no way it could be false. If you want there to be a choice, make your if statement evaluate based on a boolean variable which could be true or false based on something that happens in the program before.
Hope that solves it =)

Comment: Nice one, Nick - makes total sense and works like a dream!

Answer (score 0):

The code in the main block is not storing the return value from 
chooser() . Hence, even if the value returned from chooser() is false , it is not being used in the if block
        **chooser()**
        if True:    # condition is always true 
            temperature = F_userInput()
            result = f2c(temperature)
        else:       # never executed
            temperature = C_userInput()
            result = c2f(temperature)

Comment: @ mintekhab Yes  - many thanks for the additional info. You are quite right and I solved this by adding a variable at the **chooser()** step and the following conditional in the **main()** block